# Create new IOS app certificate and provisioning profile for existing app

Tags: ios, app-store

There is an existing app in the app store but I do not have the private key for the app signing. Now I need to update the app and would like to know if generating a new distribution certificate and provisioning profile whilst using the same bundle ID would affect anything. Please assist as I cannot proceed as I am getting "No signing certificate "iOS Distribution/development" found". Please let me know if need to explain anything better here if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just revoke the existing certificate from AppStore and create a new from your keychain with same AppId. Nothing will happen to your existing App on Store.

Comment: do I need to create as new provisioning profile as well?

Comment: @skydev yes .. you need to do that