# Will updating app store provisioning profile with new certificate cause problem to existing app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I have an app store release provisioning profile that will expire after two months and I want to update it. I have created a new distribution certificate and uploaded it. If I go to edit, change the certificate with the new one in the app store provisioning profile, save and the download the newly generated one, will that affect my released app in any way. Will it require a new release and review from Apple.

Comment: it won't break already installed apps. Only that you won't be able to sign newer apps with the old profile...

Comment: Thank you. Another detail that I forgot to add is that the application has two profiles. One is for the application target itself and the other one is for another target that is created for Push Notifications purposes. Will that make any difference.

Comment: And also will I have to do a new application release with the new profile in a specific time period to keep my application up. I mean will apple remove the app if new version with the new profile is not uploaded soon.

Comment: And also you say installed apps, will that mean that people who did not downloaded it will not be able to do so.

Comment: @mfaani I forgot to tag you in the first comment.

Comment: I am not sure if the entitlements are related to your provisioning profile, but if I remember correctly, I never had issues with notifications after updating the provisioning profile.

Regarding, whether people can download the app from the app store, yes they can, it will not affect the app on the store.

The new provisioning profile will be required, only before you update the new version to the app store, which means, you won't be able to sign the app with the old provisioning profile since it is invalidated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new IOS app certificate and provisioning profile for existing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078158/create-new-ios-app-certificate-and-provisioning-profile-for-existing-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're running into is a common problem for ALL Apple developers. Like apps rely on profiles and profiles rely on their certs (and the entitlements of their AppIDs).

And it's common for your certificate to become expired. Or to make changes to your profile and make it invalid.

An expired/invalid profile will STILL allow users to continue to use your app or install it from app store. No harm will come to them.

> tldr your profile/cert need to be only valid when you *submit* to Apple. *After distribution* that, for the that unique build, your app should work indefinitely.

It's just that you can't submit newer versions to the App Store Connect until your profile is up to date.

**Does having two profiles for two targets make a difference?**

Everything is same as I already answered. No harm will come to what you have in the app store. It's just that you won't be able to submit newer builds to the app store connect again until both profiles are valid

Comment: That will mean even if I do any changes to the profile in apple developer console (adding capabilities, changing the certificate and etc), that will not affect my application in the apple store, since it is already singed (users can download it or just use it if installed), meaning app will be indefinitely valid until I am paying my subscription.

Comment: Yes. That’s correct